# Splitter and Transacted Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

> I made a following route, to process the data atomically (with in same transaction)
>
> `from("file://home/input?moveFailed=.error&fileName=in.txt")
>       .transacted()
>       .split(body.tokenize("\n")).streaming()
>       .to("jms:queue:OUTQUEUE")`
>
> When the file in.txt has less records (500 records), I found that all 500 records gets committed
>   in the OUTQUEUE all at once. This is the desired behaviour.
>
> But when the file in.txt contains 10K or more records, then I am getting an exception and 
>   everything is rolling back. The file in.txt stays in the directory and not getting polled up
>   again.
>
> Here is the complete stacktrace
>
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[CamelDemoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
>     at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.(LoggingEvent.java:119) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/:na]
>     at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/:na]
>     at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/:na]
>     at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:692) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/:na]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:155) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$AsyncAfterTask.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:126) ~[camel-spring-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastState.lambda$run$1(MulticastProcessor.java:352) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.run(AsyncCompletionService.java:150) ~[camel-util-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$AsyncAfterTask.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:126) ~[camel-spring-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastState.lambda$run$1(MulticastProcessor.java:352) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.run(AsyncCompletionService.java:150) ~[camel-util-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$AsyncAfterTask.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:126) ~[camel-spring-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastState.lambda$run$1(MulticastProcessor.java:352) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.run(AsyncCompletionService.java:150) ~[camel-util-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$AsyncAfterTask.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:126) ~[camel-spring-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastState.lambda$run$1(MulticastProcessor.java:352) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.run(AsyncCompletionService.java:150) ~[camel-util-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:55) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$AsyncAfterTask.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:186) ~[camel-base-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the error you are seeing is a side-effect of a server-side error. By increasing the number of records in your file you are increasing the resource requirements to manage the transaction. Your JMS server might run out of resources, throws an error, and with that triggers the transaction error handler in Camel. Which uses recursion to handle the enqueued messages and doing so runs out of stack space at some point. First thing I would do is check your server logs for errors.

Comment: @Ralf - I checked the same with file endpoints too (in destination). The behaviour is same. I am getting same stack overflow error even then.

Comment: Then it is the local transaction management that requires the resources.

Comment: @Ralf.. we're using JpaTransactionManager to orchestrate the transaction, and we have a connection pooled datsource, what sort of resources you're mentioning ?, could you please elaborate

Comment: In this case it is memory. Stack memory to be precise.

Comment: @Ralf.. so what's the solution ?

Comment: Shrink the size of the transaction (your file)? Or reevaluate the requirement for the transaction.